# What is the problem in this recursive javascript function? [JS]

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hi to all I am trying to make a program in order to output when a number is Even using recursive calls. Can anybody please say me why it doesn't work as I expected?.

```
const isEven = num => {
  if (num === 0) return true;
  else if (num === 1) return false;
  //console.log(num);
  isEven(num-2);
}

isEven(16); // Epected Log: 0 but instead it returns undefined
```

Comment: You are not returning the return value of `isEven(num-2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because for arguments different than 0 or 1 there is no return value. The last line:

```
  isEven(num-2);
```

should be

```
  return isEven(num-2);
```

Comment: @phortela1n: Don't worry; it's a very common mistake.  There are many, many questions in the "recursion" tag with that same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a value.

Change:

```
isEven(num-2);
```

To:

```
return isEven(num-2);
```

Comment: Thanks you Jeremy : )